# Can we restrict a range of values for each variable in z3?

Tags: z3, z3py

For example, I have a constraint `x + y > 100`. I do not want z3 to give me values of `x` to be 1 or 2, and I do not want z3 to give values of `y` to be 1 or 2 as well.

So, x and y can be any number except 1 or 2.

Can we enforce such restriction on z3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course.. Simply assert `x > 2 AND y > 2`. Here it is in z3py:

```
from z3 import *

x = Int('x')
y = Int('y')

s = Solver()
s.add (x > 2)
s.add (y > 2)
s.add (x+y > 100)

s.check()
print s.model()
```

Z3 prints:

```
$ python a.py
[y = 3, x = 98]
```

Comment: Would that add up to the computational complexity if I have multiple (a lot) sets of such restrictions? For example, if I want `x` not to be 1, 3, 100, etc for `n` number of terms and `n` is relatively huge. Would it drastically slow down the computation?

Comment: Impossible to tell without trying: Also depends on the complexity of your constraints. If they are all simple comparisons like this, however, I'm sure z3 would do a good job. Give it a shot and if it performs bad we can look further into it.

Comment: Does it make a different (theoretically) if I put these restriction constraints in front, rather than at the back?

Comment: Order shouldn't matter, really. I'd like to know if you find otherwise.